# Android - Display part of a large image

Tags: android, imageview

Is there Anyway to Display part of a large image - the image is 16000*320
When Ive tried this in Android Studio using ImageView I can usually get what looks like its going to work under activity_main.xml Design, until I build .apk then the image disapears and running it on my Tablet it is also blank.

Comment: use `BitmapRegionDecoder`

Comment: Could you add some code? Like the xml in which you're adding your image?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - my xml files have been loads including scrollview/imageview

Answer (score 0):

Add an ImageView in your layout xml file:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

In your Activity:

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
```

And then use `BitmapRegionDecoder`:

```
// Get image width and height:
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("large_image.jpg");
BitmapFactory.Options tmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
tmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, tmpOptions);
int width = tmpOptions.outWidth;
int height = tmpOptions.outHeight;

// Crop image:
// Crop a rect with 200 pixel width and height from center of image
BitmapRegionDecoder bitmapRegionDecoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(inputStream, false);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(width / 2 - 100, height / 2 - 100, width / 2 + 100, height / 2 + 100), options);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Code from [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder)

Comment: Thank you I will try this do I need anything in my xml?

Comment: You only need an `ImageView` that will display the cropped image. Last line of sample code assigns the cropped image to `mImageView`

Comment: Thanks agian im getting the following problems - ive added mImageView as the id of the ImageView http://ibb.co/gXRO7F

Comment: You have to define an ImageView in your xml and define it in your activity. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you for all your help I still have a few lines highlighted red as shown in the picture in the Following link http://i.imgur.com/i5OFokc.png