# Displaying only certain part of image on a Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am currently drawing an image on a canvas in Android Studio like so:

```
public class Floor{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    Drawable image;

    public Floor(int x, int y, int width, int height, Context context) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.image = this.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.floorimage);
    }

    // this method is called in the draw loop
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        Rect imageBounds = new Rect(this.x, this.y, this.x + this.width, this.y + this.height);

        this.image.setBounds(imageBounds);
        this.image.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

So the image size is set according to the width and height.
I however don't want to reset the image size, I want to draw the part of the image, that is included in the width and height.

**To vizualize**:

[image: I want to only draw the separated part of the image but still other objects outside the separated part]

I am aware of this thread:
[Android - Display part of a large image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664051/android-display-part-of-a-large-image)

However that thread only shows how to solve my problem for an ImageView.
Does anyone have a solution for doing this in a canvas?

Comment: Your "what I want" image is really not too clear, b/c it just shows a couple black lines added to the picture, but I think you want [`clipRect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for, clipRect() does cut away the image like I want it to, however it cuts everything within the canvas (I don't want that). I have updated the image to make it more clear hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Floor.draw() :

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

 Rect canvasBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();         //get the current clip(Canvas drawing area)
 this.image.setBounds(canvasBounds);      //same bounds as canvas, so image is the same size. We clip next

 Rect imageBounds=new Rect(0,0,this.width,this.height); //You should move this line to constructor. You know, performance and all.                                                                

 canvas.save();                 //save the current clip. You can't use canvasBounds to restore it later, there is no setClipBounds()
 canvas.clipRect(imageBounds); //clip the canvas so you draw only the width and height u want
 this.image.draw(canvas);
 canvas.restore();       //restore the Canvas clip. 

 //do other drawings with full size canvas
```

}

Happy coding!